# Installation errors during installation of spaCy on Mac

Tags: spacy

```
enter code hereerror: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-build-g2pxxnlc/murmurhash/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-wjdy1tf5-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-build-g2pxxnlc/murmurhash/

```
enter code hereFailed building wheel for regex
```

Running setup.py clean for regex
Failed to build regex
Installing collected packages: html5lib, pathlib, regex, msgpack-python, tqdm, toolz
  Found existing installation: html5lib 0.999999999
    Uninstalling html5lib-0.999999999:
      Successfully uninstalled html5lib-0.999999999
  Found existing installation: regex 2017.11.9
    Uninstalling regex-2017.11.9:
      Successfully uninstalled regex-2017.11.9
  Running setup.py install for regex ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/venkateshpala/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-build-ltar9s28/regex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-edv9r7il-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /Users/venkateshpala/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:351: UserWarning: Normalizing '2017.04.05' to '2017.4.5'
      normalized_version,
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    copying Python3/regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    copying Python3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    copying Python3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_regex' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/Python3
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/venkateshpala/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/venkateshpala/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/venkateshpala/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c Python3/_regex.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/Python3/_regex.o
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

Rolling back uninstall of regex
Command "/Users/venkateshpala/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-build-ltar9s28/regex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-edv9r7il-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hl/zm3tpkmd4ws1b21nk792wdj80000gn/T/pip-build-ltar9s28/regex/

Answer (score 1):

The thing is there are some libraries that we(macOs users) can't install unless there is Xcode installed or binaries of Xcode is what I was asked for during the time of Installation after which I was able to download and run the spaCy on my Machine.

Answer (score 0):

in your log:

```
command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Installing `gcc` might fix the error, or another compatible compiler symlinked to `gcc`.